# React datepicker disable entering date manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using React date-picker for my form. Currently it's working well, but the user can delete the date and enter whatever values. How do I restrict it?

This is my code:

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

    <DatePicker
    name="invoiceDate"
    className="form-control form-control-sm"
    type="text"
    size="sm"
    placeholder=""
    selected={date}
    minDate={new Date()}
    value={values.setDate}
    onChange={datePickerChange}
    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    />
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just add this line of code to `DatePicker` :

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}}
```

After adding this `event`, your component's code will be like the below code :

```
<DatePicker
    name="invoiceDate"
    className="form-control form-control-sm"
    type="text"
    size="sm"
    placeholder=""
    selected={date}
    minDate={new Date()}
    value={values.setDate}
    onChange={datePickerChange}
    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
    }}
  />
```

[image: Edit patient-silence-ybz45]

Comment: This solution is works, unlike official one form github.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line of code to DatePicker:

```
disabledKeyboardNavigation={false}
format="dd/MM/yy"
```

You can add your date format; It will only take date.

Answer (score 1):

I think `onBeforeInput` should be used in this case, as opposed to `onKeyDown`.

So just simply:

```
onBeforeInput={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}}
```

The reason being, that `onKeyDown` prevents a lot of 'normal' functionality from working when the `input` is focused. E.g.:

- Page reload with `CTRL` + `R`
- Opening devtools with `F12`
- Going to the next input with `Tab`

And in case of `ReactDatePicker`, the `customInput` property has to be used to pass in an `input` that has `onBeforeInput` overridden as explained.

Answer (score 0):

#### The accepted answer  does not hide keyboard in mobile.

---

You need to use a custom input component. Instead of input, use a `HTMLButtonElement`. You may style it to look like a `HTMLInputElement`.

```
type DatePickerCustomInputProps = { value: string; onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void }

const DatePickerCustomInput = forwardRef(
  ({ value, onClick }: DatePickerCustomInputProps, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement>) => (
    <button type="button" className={"date-picker-custom-input"} onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      {value}
    </button>
  )
)
```

```
<DatePicker
  dateFormat={setting.datoFormat}
  selected={new Date(value)}
  onSelect={(date: Date) => {
    onChange(date.toISOString())
  }}
  customInput={React.createElement(DatePickerButtonInput)}
  onChange={(date: Date) => {
    onChange(date.toISOString())
  }}
/>
```

If you do not use typescript, do this:

```
<DatePicker
  dateFormat={setting.datoFormat}
  selected={new Date(value)}
  onSelect={(date: Date) => {
    onChange(date.toISOString())
  }}
  customInput={<DatePickerButtonInput />}
  onChange={(date: Date) => {
    onChange(date.toISOString())
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `<DatePicker />` component:

```
<DatePicker onKeyDown={(e) => {e.preventDefault()}} />
```

This will prevent anything from being typed in the input as the prop name suggests

Answer (score 0):

accepted answer does not solve the problem accross browsers.

you need to do a combination of hacks to get this working on IOS, Safari, FireFox, Smart TV Browsers etc..

There is no need to make a custom input if you are just trying to resolve the keyboard showing up on Mobile/Tablet/TVs.

```
  const handleFocus = (e: ReactClickEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { target } = e;

    if (target) {
      target.readOnly = true;  // -------> this for all others
      target.blur(); //  ------> this for ios iphone, TV Browsers, Ipad, Safari
    }
  };

  <ReactDatePicker 
     ..whatever your props are
     onFocus={handleFocus} /// <----- add this prop
   />
```